# Unable to create a CoudFormation RDS template which provision new instance from point in time snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I've trying to write a CloudFormation to provision a new RDS instance from the point in time snapshot an existing RDS DB.

However, I came to know that you can't specify db-name when you provide a snapshot in CloudFormation template and thus it will always restore it to the original DB.

I have got [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-an-aws-cloudformation-custom-resource-to-manage-amazon-rds-point-in-time-recovery/) article for the same on aws blogs, though I'm looking if there is any out of the box solution for the same.

### Edit 1

RDS snippet from my Cloud Formation

```
Resources:
  MyDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: Fn::If ["UseDbSnapshot", !Ref AWS:NoValue, !Ref MyDBName]
      DBSecurityGroups:
      - !Ref MyDbSecurityByEC2SecurityGroup
      - !Ref MyDbSecurityByCIDRIPGroup
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      DBInstanceClass: db.m1.small
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: root
      MasterUserPassword: password
      DBSnapshotIdentifier: Fn::If ["UseDbSnapshot", !Ref DBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref AWS::NoValue]
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
```

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the relevant cloudformation where you're trying to do this?

Comment: @maafk: updated in the original post

Comment: Thanks @jps for pointing that out.

Comment: Restoring to the same `DBName` is by design, as it's restoring a copy of the MySQL db. Once restored, you can run something like `RENAME TABLE old_db.table TO new_db.table;` if you want to change the name of the schema

Comment: @maafk AWS console gives a way to do the same, so I was just wondering if there's a way to do it using AWS CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind, that a couple of RDS properties (such as MasterUsername) are not customizable when you want to restore from snapshot. The AWS documentation says:

> If you specify the SourceDBInstanceIdentifier or DBSnapshotIdentifier property, don't specify this property. The value is inherited from the source DB instance or snapshot.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

So just omit those parameters like this:

```yaml
Parameters:
  DBSnapshotIdentifier:
    Description: 'Optional identifier for the DB cluster snapshot from which you want to restore'
    Type: String
    Default: ''

Conditions:
  HasDBSnapshotIdentifier: !Not [!Equals [!Ref DBSnapshotIdentifier, '']]


Resources:
  DBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      ...
      DBSnapshotIdentifier: !If [HasDBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref DBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      KmsKeyId: !If [HasDBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue', !If [HasEncryption, !Ref KmsKey, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']]
      MasterUsername: !If [HasDBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue', !Ref MasterUsername]
      MasterUserPassword: !If [HasDBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue', !Ref MasterPassword]
      StorageEncrypted: !If [HasDBSnapshotIdentifier, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue', !If 
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks user10374572, for correcting my template. I am trying to find a way to provision a new instance from point in time snapshot of an existing RDS instance.
I have learnt that there's no direct way, so was wondering what all workarounds can be adopted to achieve the same.